# Why are there $40$ paths in a $3\times 3$ grid?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

If I have a thread of length $4$ that I want to lay on a $2\times 2$, there are $8$ ways to do it, apparently. That because from every node I can go clockwise or counter clockwise, right?

But similarly, it says that for $3\times 3$ there are $40$ ways to do it, but I could only count $20$ (like it says [here](http://oeis.org/A120443)). Why is that?

Comment: Did you count the reversed paths?

Comment: You say it's $8$ for $2\times 2$, yet your OEIS link says $4$. Exploring this discrepancy probably leads you to your answer.

Comment: Indeed your OEIS link says "undirected" and illustrates the three types

Comment: @Arthur In the 2x2 case the reversed paths are taken into consideration too, right? So on that principle there should be 40 for the 3x3 case. But I was thinking of the case where it looks like this: 1->2->3->6->5->4->7->8->5

Comment: You have a typo and probably intended 1->2->3->6->5->4->7->8->9 - that is the first type illustrated in [OEIS A120443](http://oeis.org/A120443).  There are 4 paths of that shape with reflection and rotation, growing to 8 if you take direction into account.  Then there are two other shapes each with 8 possibilities with rotation and reflection and 16 if taking direction into account. $8+16+16=40$ as in [OEIS A096969](http://oeis.org/A096969)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that for $3\times 3$ you want to cover all the nodes. In this case there are $40$ ways to do it if it matters which end is the "start" and which is the "finish", but only $20$ if this doesn't matter. It's exactly the same for $2\times 2$, where you found $8$ ways because you distinguish between "clockwise from top left" and "anticlockwise from bottom left", but the OEIS says $4$ ways because it counts these as one way (which you can follow in either direction).

Comment: So I just reverse the "arrows" and on that principle there should be 40 for the 3x3 case. But I was thinking of the case where it looks like this: 1->2->3->6->5->4->7->8->5, when I don't cross every node. The length of the thread is the same.

Comment: @a0142204 Missing a point and visiting another twice would not be a *Hamiltonian path*

Comment: @Henry but then what about the 2x2 case where I always get back to the starting node?

Comment: @a0142204 Visiting each node once and then getting back to the starting point is a *Hamiltonian cycle*.  There are fewer of these than *Hamiltonian paths*, and none on a $3\times3$ grid for parity reasons